# Position left sidebar with CSS

Tags: html, css, sidebar

I am trying to design a layout with a left sidebar and a centered header. I have the header and sidebar in a wrapper div so that they can be centered on the page, but I want the sidebar to be a little left of the header like in this screenshot[image]

How can I achieve this? Right now, when I re-size the window, the sidebar won't follow the header. Any help would be appreciated, I am still learning CSS. Thanks.

Here is my HTML and CSS (note: I had a margin: 0 auto 0 15px for the nav but took it out):

```
<body>
<div id="wrapper">
    <header>

    </header>

    <nav>
        <ul>

        </ul>
    </nav>
</div>
```

```
    body {
    margin:0;
    padding: 5px;
    background-color: #121212;
}

#wrapper {
    margin:0 auto 0 auto;
    width:1024;
}

header {
    /* IE10 Consumer Preview */ 
    background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #0C0DA6 0%, #0E0B58 100%);

    /* Mozilla Firefox */ 
    background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #0C0DA6 0%, #0E0B58 100%);

    /* Opera */ 
    background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top, #0C0DA6 0%, #0E0B58 100%);

    /* Webkit (Safari/Chrome 10) */ 
    background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0, #0C0DA6), color-stop(1, #0E0B58));

    /* Webkit (Chrome 11+) */ 
    background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #0C0DA6 0%, #0E0B58 100%);

    /* W3C Markup, IE10 Release Preview */ 
    background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, #0C0DA6 0%, #0E0B58 100%);

    width: 768px;
    height:100px;
    border-radius: 4px;
    border: 2px solid #adadad;
    margin:0 auto 0 auto;
}

nav {
    /* IE10 Consumer Preview */ 
    background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #0C0DA6 0%, #0E0B58 100%);

    /* Mozilla Firefox */ 
    background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #0C0DA6 0%, #0E0B58 100%);

    /* Opera */ 
    background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top, #0C0DA6 0%, #0E0B58 100%);

    /* Webkit (Safari/Chrome 10) */ 
    background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0, #0C0DA6), color-stop(1, #0E0B58));

    /* Webkit (Chrome 11+) */ 
    background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #0C0DA6 0%, #0E0B58 100%);

    /* W3C Markup, IE10 Release Preview */ 
    background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, #0C0DA6 0%, #0E0B58 100%);

    width:230px;
    height:235px;
    border-radius: 4px;
    border: 2px solid #adadad;

}
```

Comment: Please create a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) to get help faster.

Comment: Here is the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/WMYmV/

Comment: Does the solution below work for you? If yes, you should mark the answer as accepted so that it'll show up as solved on the questions page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you go: http://jsfiddle.net/WMYmV/1/

Changed style:

```
header {
    width: 538px; //(768px - width of sidebar)
    margin: 0 auto 0 230px;
}
```

Comment: it works, thank you. is there a way to have the sidebar and header center as I adjust the window size?

Comment: Your header and sidebar have fixed widths. What does it mean to center them? If the available width becomes smaller, you'll just get a horizontal scroll bar.

Comment: What I mean is that the sidebar and header dimensions don't change, but to have them both be centered on the page. That was my intention with putting them inside a wrapper div. Edit: nvm I got it to work, just needed to adjust the width of my wrapper div. Thank you again.